# How to determine what version of TLS an app is using?

Tags: ruby, ssl

We connect to an API that is discontinuing support for TLS 1.0.

How can I determine what version of TLS we are using?

(editing; the framework/library information that were originally part of this question ended up not being relevant to the answer, which applies to a much wider range of situations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an endpoint that you can connect to with anything, and it will report back to you significant details about how you connected to them, including the TLS version that you used:

https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check

I also found this, which merely tells you whether you met PayPal's standards for connectivity or not:

https://tlstest.paypal.com/